# HTML5 video on mobile phones - Chrome 55 does not autoplay and mute?

Tags: android, ios, html, google-chrome, html5-video

Chrome browser on my Android phone is version 55. According to this [doc](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay), 'Muted autoplay for video is supported by Chrome for Android as of version 53.'

This is my code:

```html
<div class="item-video">
  <video width="560" height="315" autoplay muted controls loop playsinline>
            <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
  <a href="yourpage.html" class="button-video"></a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

I even tested their [sample page](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/muted-autoplay/index.html) on my Android, and not working at all!